# Serviceworker Chunk with CommonsChunkPlugin doesn't work, webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service-worker, commonschunkplugin

I'm trying to create a serviceworker chunk (sw.js) with webpack2 using the `CommonsChunkPlugin` but when trying to register /sw.js as a serviceworker I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined`.

Apparently webpackJsonp is for async loading of chunks and is messing up my serviceworker file. Is there anyway to remove async loading for the serviceworker chunk?

My webpack config:

```json
{
  entry: {
    main: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${host}:${port}`,
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './index.jsx',
    ],
    sw: './sw.js',
    vendor: [...],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] },
  performance: { hints: false },
  context: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    host,
    port,
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader'),
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css'),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest'],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you extract only your webpack runtime code (which has webpackJsonp defined) into your manifest bundle and load it before all other script, it should work.

So, you would want to rewrite as

```
plugins: [
   ...
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
  ],
```